# What sort of mortar do I need for an outside/porch installation of large tiles

Tags: tiling

I have a 46sqf porch where I want to install tiles. These are large tiles 2'x2'. I am planning to also install redguard to provide waterproofing and crack prevention. I am told that I need a special mortar which is the only one that can take the thaw/freeze cycles that we have here in Canada

Comment: When I put down 20" square tile; I bought the can that said "for ceramic tile on concrete". It has worked for 20 years.

Comment: I put tiles on my porch in Ohio over 500sf and I used thin set with acrylic add mix as the liquid it gets super cold there -20s  the job lasted the 2 winters we were there, I did seal the grout very well so no water could get in today I would use epoxy based grout keeping water out is critical water gets in and nothing will stop the ice from breaking the tiles up.

Comment: yeah totally agree, keeping water out is going to be critical. Now this porch has a roof and on one side is the garage wall, so it is sheltered to a degree. On the other side of the garage wall there is a built in planter that is like 2' high so that also adds more protection.  I wish I had the motivation to actually turn this into a hallway but I can't afford to pay the prices we see these days on the market, Maybe I could but I do not see the ROI being there I would rather spend the money on something else to improve the living conditions

Comment: You also want a thinset formulated for "large format tile."

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your porch is concrete so you'll need a modified mortar. Modified mortar is similar to regular mortar but it has additives added to it that help with waterproofing and the freeze-thaw cycle. If you use an epoxy grout after setting the tiles, you probably wouldn't need the RedGard so that would be up to you.

Comment: freeze-thaw means: contraction/expansion, and water freezes and breaks down the materials. The first is something that I can manage  by using larger grout lines. The water must be stopped at the entry point, grout lines so yes epoxy grout is a must. The reduard will decouple the tiles/mortar from the underneath concrete expansion/contraction so that should be fine.  I am using "Versabond-LFT professional medium bed mortar is a non-sag,nonslump, polymer modified mortar for use with large format porcelain,
ceramic and natural stone tile." So it is a modified mortar so I guess I will be fine.

Comment: The HomeDepot guy told me that I need this https://www.homedepot.ca/product/custom-building-products-megalite-30-lb-white-crack-prevention-mortar/1000166925 since it is THE ONLY product they had on the shelf that can deal with the freeze/thaw stuff. The product was too expensive so I went with Versabond which I can still return if someone tells me it is not appropriate

Comment: @MiniMe, the technical information for the thinset should explicitly mention that it is formulated for both indoor and outdoor.